# How to create PDF file with password protection after download?

Tags: pdfsharp

I have a new requirement: PDF file should be password protected after download. It should be password protected not at the time of view, but at the time of download and when tried to open. I want to use PDFsharp.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Protect Document sample:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/ProtectDocument-sample.ashx

And don't forget to pass the "user" password to the user. User must (*) enter the password after the download when opening the file.

If you want the user to enter a password before the download, then the password protection must be implemented on the web site, not in the PDF file.

(*) Adobe Reader will prompt for the password, but other programs may display the file without password.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasH but which softwares are you talking about any software which can be used to combine two pdf files and will not prompt password actually Adobe didn't allow user to read pdf file we did code using pdfsharp to authenticate user by password.